# Please Help me with selenium on Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Good evening, I'm trying to do some tests with selenium in Firefox, but I'm stuck, I can not click on a button, because I got the message accepting cookies and that does not allow me to continue with the test, I do not know how to make selenium accept cookies.

This is the message it gave me:
`An exception occurred: ElementClickInterceptedException Message: Element <select id="tramiteGrupo[1]" class="mf-input__l" name="tramiteGrupo[1]"> is not clickable at point (470,571) because another element <a class="small cli-plugin-button cli-plugin-main-button" href="#"> obscures it`

I want to get selenium to accept cookies and be able to continue entering parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Get Selenium to pause(check docs on how to pause, something like `Thread.sleep(2000);`) for a minute just before it clicks the "Accept cookies" button and try click the button yourself when it's paused. So you will be able to see what element is blocking it.

Then use "page scroll up"/"page scroll down"/x/y/whatever to move it so it will not be blocked when trying to click the button.

Comment: I have tried those, but the checks that are throwing it off aren't behaviour based. This can be proven by starting the browser with selenium but doing things manually. It still blocks you.